# transfer php-variable to javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have incorporated this simple datetimepicker : http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#rest_examples

So it looks

```
<?php $tabname = "brightness"; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#datumstartbrightness').timepicker();
</script>
...
<input type="text" name="datumstart<?php echo $tabname; ?>" 
                id="datumstart<?php echo    $tabname; ?>"/> 
...
```

With this code it works and datetimepicker appears !

But with this ...

```
<?php $tabname = "brightness"; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#datumstart<?php echo $tabname; ?>').timepicker();
</script>
...
<input type="text" name="datumstart<?php echo $tabname; ?>" id="datumstart<?php echo     $tabname; ?>"/> 
...
```

DateTimePicker doesn't appear. What can be wrong with this line

**$('#datumstart').timepicker();**

Comment: Have you checked the actual output in your inspector/source? And you're JS is executed after the DOM is loaded right?

Comment: There is nothing wrong there: `$('#datumstart<?php echo $tabname; ?>').timepicker();`

Comment: I noticed something else. `datumstart` and `brightness` are Dutch and English. You are using id's and classes with mixed up languages. It's not a big deal, but it's nice to have it all in English. Makes it more uniform and makes stuff a bit more descriptive/obvious for other programmers who don't speak the native language :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the ready-state first before you can call jQuery-Functions: So try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('#datumstart<?php echo $tabname; ?>').timepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I agree with the point that we need do the ready-state first. However, the `echo` will not output the space in the PHP code except this space is a string constant.

Comment: @Susanne92 you're welcome. You can thanking by "accepting" the answer. Simply click on the tick on the left.